# What is the difference /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages vs /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages?

Tags: python, libraries

What is the difference between:

```
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu, this seems to be:

- `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`: things installed by `dpkg`/`apt`
- `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`: things installed using `pip`

Comment: are you sure? what foundation did you use?

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` contains non-host-specific modules installed by the system with the package manager, for example on Ubuntu with `sudo apt install safeeyes`.

However, `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages` contains modules that you installed yourself system-wide through a package manager, for example with `sudo pip install safeeyes`.

Note that installing modules using `pip` in user mode (`without sudo`), installs packages into `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`, for instance: `pip install safeeyes`

---

Also, check the [Linux filesystem hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).